# Is $\log(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics, computational-complexity

I need to prove or disprove that $\log(\log(n)) = O(\log(n))$.

I've tried the following:

$\log(\log(n)) \le c * \log(n)$

$\log(\log(n)) \le \log(n^c)$

$\log(n) \le n^c$

But I got stuck, and I couldn't figure out where to go.

Comment: Have you considered trying Lh'opital's law for their quotient?

Comment: I can't see how using l'hospital would be useful.

Comment: $\log(\log(n))=o(\log(n))$ because $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{\log(x)}{x}=0$, in particular $\log(\log(n))=\mathcal{O}(\log(n))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $c=1$: you just have to check that there is an $n_0$ such that $\log(\log n)\le\log n$ whenever $n\ge n_0$. The log function is monotone increasing, so this amounts to checking that $\log n\le n$ or, if you prefer, that $n\le e^n$.

Answer (score 0):

By substitution,  $\;\log(\log n)=o(\log n)$. And 
$$f=o(g)\implies  f=O(g).$$